# historisation concept / library / framework in java or php?

Tags: java, php, design-patterns, data-structures

I am looking for a historicizing concept for php or java.

Imagine this usecase:

1. you are on page 1
2. you delete a random entry
3. on page 2 you create an entry with random content
4. on page 3 you delete all together on page
5. 4 you add a random entry

now I want to 'undo' and go back to step 3.

Is there something out there that would me having a nice history concept out of the box?

E.g. I guess you would need something that keeps the model as a set of subsequent changes to a base. The view would have the calculated results of these changes. Going back would be very easy, just execute only a subset.

Comment: Look at the [Memoization](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/08/20/memoization.html) design pattern.

Comment: Reminds me of [something](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) I read from the great Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this sort of thing, you need to remember the sequence of actions you have performed together with enough information to restore everything to the state your system was in before each action.

The most common way to achieve this is to represent the actions allowed in your system using the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), and ensure that each `Command` object has both an `execute()` and `undo()` operation.  Frequently, supporting this `undo()` also involves use of the [Memento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) to save the state before the action so that it can be restored.